# Find eigenvalues without computing the distance matrix in Ncuts implementation

Tags: memory, graph, cluster-analysis, large-data, image-segmentation

I want to implement Ncuts algorithm for an image of size 1248 x 378 x 1 but the adjacency matrix will be (1248 x 378 ) x (1248 x 378 ) which needs about 800 gb of RAM. Even if i most of it is zero, still it needs too much memory. I do need this matrix though to compute the normalized cut. Is there any way that i can find the eigenvalues without actually calculate the whole matrix?

Answer (score 2):

If most of the matrix is zero,, then don't use a dense format.

Instead use a **sparse matrix**.